# How to load JavaScript libraries using a Blazor server-side application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an existing *html* theme with some *JavaScripts* that I want to incorporate into a *Blazor server-side* application.
To incorporate the existing *html* theme, I added the *JavaScript* tags on the `_Host.cshtml` file, copied all the theme *html* tags on the `Index.razor` file and placed all the `css` & `js` library files under the `wwwroot` folder.
The web page works as expected as long as I comment out the 
`<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` line in the `_Host.cshtml` file. However, if a leave this line uncomment some *JavaScripts* libraries don't get loaded. It doesn't matter if I place the `<script>` tags in the `<head>` side or in the `<body>` side or before or after the `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` line.
Is there a way to load *JavaScript* libraries?
This is how the `_Host.cshtml` file looks like:

```
        @page "/"
        @namespace TPAGE.Pages
        @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
        @{
            Layout = null;
        }

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Test Page</title>
          <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

          <!-- Favicon -->
          <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="icon">

          <!-- Google Fonts -->
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Montserrat:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
          <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
          <link href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
          <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">     
            
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <app>
                <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
            </app>

            <div id="blazor-error-ui">
                <environment include="Staging,Production">
                    An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
                </environment>
                <environment include="Development">
                    An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
                </environment>
                <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
                <a class="dismiss"></a>
            </div>

            <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

            <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
            <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Contact Form JavaScript File -->
            <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

            <!-- Template Main Javascript File -->
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by removing all these lines from the `<body>` tag on the `_Host.cshtml` file.

```
            <app>
                <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
            </app>

            <div id="blazor-error-ui">
                <environment include="Staging,Production">
                    An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
                </environment>
                <environment include="Development">
                    An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
                </environment>
                <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
                <a class="dismiss"></a>
            </div>
```

And then I added the *HTML* theme tags in that place.  So the `<body>` looks something like this:

```
<body>

    <PASTE ALL THE THEME HTML TAGS GO HERE>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="theme/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="theme/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theme/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript File -->
    <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

    <!-- Template Main Javascript File -->
    <script src="theme/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```